# Azure app registration for authenticating to different resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-app-registration

I am new to Azure and would like to understand sone best practices for authenticating to different Azure resources using Azure App registration.

Do I need to create separate app registration for authenticating to different Azure resources like Azure App service, Azure Data Factory , Azure app service etc? Or Can we use one app registration?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use an App Registration with multiple resources.
One way to think of it is an App Registration provides granular RBAC access to specific azure resources.
Also consider monitoring all access to your app registrations by enabling the logging.
And now you can monitor risky behaviour using Defender for APIs.

here's one of many references on this topic:
[enter link description here](https://techieberry.com/azure-ad-app-registration/)